# Vertical Component of Normal Force on Bank

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, centripetal-force

[image]

Consider the above diagram.

Apparantely the vertical component of the normal force should balance $mg$.

However, this cannot be the case. The normal force is equal to the component of $mg$ perpendicular to the bank. As it is a component of $mg$, its magnitude must be less than the magnitude of $mg$. Again when we resolve the normal force, into a horizontal and vertical component, the magnitude of the horizontal component of the normal force must be less than the magnitude of the normal force. Then it follows that the horizontal component of the normal force is less than that of $mg$, and they cannot balance. Even drawing a scale diagram with the vector lengths representing magnitudes of forces supports my claim.

So how can the vertical component of the normal force actually balance $mg$?

Comment: What makes you think the vertical component of the normal force has to balance mg?

Comment: @BobD What balances $mg$ then? otherwise we get acceleration downwards

Comment: There is a third force... (although sometimes it is absent, but now we're entering a slippery slope).

Comment: @QuinGardinerBax you get acceleration along the incline due to the component of mg along the incline

Comment: @QuinGardinerBax in other words the normal reaction force balances the component of mg perpendicular to the plane and the unbalanced component of mg parallel to the plane results in the acceleration parallel to the plane

Comment: Do you understand now?

Answer (score 2):

In comments you said that you reasoned that the forces must be balanced, because, "otherwise we get acceleration downwards".

This is correct. And in fact in the given scenario there **will** be acceleration downwards.

Unless, of course, there is another force acting upwards along the sloping surface. In the real world, friction often provides such a force, which is why we don't always see objects slide whenever they are placed on an incline.

Answer (score 1):

> So how can the vertical component of the normal force actually balance
> $mg$?

$mg$ ***is*** the vertical force acting on the mass.

It has a component acting perpendicular to the incline which is balanced by the normal reaction force of the incline for a net force of zero, and therefore no acceleration perpendicular to the incline.

It has another component parallel to the incline. In the absence of friction, that component is not balanced, which results in acceleration parallel to the incline.

Hope this helps.